# Making an array out of doubles from a text file

Tags: java, arrays

I need to read a file of grades and input them into an array. I cant seem to figure it out though. Any suggestions. Thanks for your help :)
The grades.txt file looks like this:

```
90.0
71.5
87.9
95.0
98.1
```

Code:

```
File file1 = new File("grades.txt");
Scanner gradesFile = new Scanner(file1);
String line = gradesFile.nextLine();

//create array
double[] array = new double[12];

//variable to increment
int u = 0;

//loop to put data into array
while(gradesFile.hasNextDouble())

    array[u] = gradesFile.nextDouble();
    u += 1;

gradesFile.close();
```

Comment: You need `{` and `}` to surround the body of your `while` loop...

Comment: @hnefatl You should write that comment as an answer! Then others can see the solution, and you'll get credit for your answer.

Comment: (Functional) duplicate of [for loop without braces in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221915/for-loop-without-braces-in-java).

Comment: that wasnt the problem. it wont store the values into the array. It doesnt increment down through the file.

Comment: @NileHorse You'll need to edit your answer to provide a [mcve] describing exactly what input you give and what output you expect, then.

Comment: @NileHorse it will help if you can show us at least part of the "grades.txt" file.

Answer (score 3):

A. As @hnefatl said you need to group statements in the loop,

```
while(<condition>) {
   statement1;
   ...
   statementN;
}
```

otherwise only next one executes.

```
while(<condition>) statement1;
...
```

B. When you did `String line = gradesFile.nextLine();`
you got full first line from file and Scanner position is at next line if there is any.

So by doing `gradesFile.hasNextDouble()` after that, Scaner looks for double in next line.

If you'd like to use `nextLine()` and your doubles are "one-per-line" you need to work with them in a loop as:

```
    Scanner gradesFile = new Scanner(file1);
    // create array
    double[] array = new double[12];
    // variable to increment
    int u = 0;
    // loop to put data into array
    while (gradesFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = gradesFile.nextLine();
        array[u] = Double.parseDouble(line);
        u += 1;
    }

    gradesFile.close();
```

or if you'd like to use `nextDouble()` you do not mix it with `nextLine()`

```
    Scanner gradesFile = new Scanner(file1);
    // create array
    double[] array = new double[12];
    // variable to increment
    int u = 0;
    // loop to put data into array
    while (gradesFile.hasNextDouble()) {            
        array[u] = gradesFile.nextDouble();
        u++;
    }

    gradesFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply scan the double value in your file and store in the array as below

```
Scanner scan;
//Data file
File file = new File(grades.txt");
//Array to store the double read from file
double[] array = new double[10];
int i =0;

try {
    scan = new Scanner(file);

    //Scan while the file has next double value
    while(scan.hasNextDouble())
    {
        //Save the double value read from text file and store to array
        array[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        i++;
    }

}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To print what you have stored in your array

```
for(int y = 0; y < array.length;y++)
{
   System.out.println(array[y]);
}
```